# Is "Disabled badge holder electric vehicle recharging point only" ambiguous?

Tags: phrase-meaning, ambiguity

Is there any confusion about the following sign text?

> Disabled badge holder electric vehicle recharging point only

Is the wording ambiguous? Could it be interpreted as:

> Disabled badge holder **or** electric vehicle recharging point only

Could it possibly mean the following?

> The parking bay is exclusively for disabled badge holders, but it is also available for electric vehicle recharging, without displaying a disabled badge

[image: photo of sign]

Comment: There is often scope for multiple interpretations when telegraphese is used. The problem here is that legal interpretations trump strict logic when it comes to court rulings.

Comment: It would depend on whether there was a charger there, whether there was a clearly marked space, and what else was there (road markings, parking meter, etc). But if there was a charger and a parking space, it would clearly be a space for charging for disabled badge holders only. If you're contesting a parking ticket, maybe ask elsewhere.

Comment: The recharging point for electric vehicles of disabled badge holders. I do not think it is ambiguous since only vehicles are recharged.

Comment: From a purely theoretical viewpoint, the formulation is syntactically ambiguous in more than one way, but, as Lambie point out, it is unlikely to be so in real life, and certainly not in the way the OP suggests.

Comment: Multiply ambiguous, like every written text. Though I don't know why the author has tried so hard to turn a complex sentence into a complex noun phrase that's hard to parse.

Comment: I would say confusing rather than ambiguous. Very poorly worded. That can be excused if the sign is brief, but this one doesn't even have that going for it.

Comment: The syntax is ambiguous, but one interpretation would be nonsense, because you can't recharge disabled badge holders, so there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 10):

It appears to say that you must both be recharging and having (and presumably displaying) a disability badge.

I can't see any way to interpret that such that only one of the conditions applies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to interpret it that way; usually there would be something (such as "or", a slash, or a comma) between the two options (so in this case between "disabled badge holder" and "electric vehicle recharging").

However, if you want to focus only on syntax, then there are other possible ambiguities. For example, you could interpret "disabled" as modifying only "badge", or even as modifying the rest of the phrase ("badge holder electric vehicle recharging point"). Of course, such interpretations don't seem to make sense, so I doubt that this sign would likely be misinterpreted.

As others have noted, though, the law often interprets English in its own way, so if you're fighting a ticket, then you may want to ask a lawyer, too.